# How to run the same MPI program multiple times

Tags: mpi, mpich, mpic++

I have an MPI program to calculate a sorting time. I run it with `mpirun -np 2 mpiSort`. So this gives me the sorting time by 2 processes.

I want to get the sorting time for 5 times to average them. How do I do that automatically?

If I do a loop in the `mpiSort` program. It actually executes 5(times) x 2(processes) = 10 times.

Edit: The `mpiSort` does the sort in parallel. Basically, I'm trying to do `mpirun -np 2 mpiSort` without typing it 5 times. Because I want to do the same for 4 cores, 8 cores.

Answer (score 0):

You could run on five cores using `mpirun -np 5 mpiSort` and add an `MPI_gather` at the end. Is the sort code actually using MPI (i.e. calls `MPI_init` at the beginning?). Assuming you are, you can run on 5 cores and simply average at the end with a reduce,

```
# include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    int ierr, rank, nprocs, root=0;
    double time, buf;
    ierr = MPI_Init ( &argc, &argv );
    ierr = MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    ierr = MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
    time = 0.5;
    ierr = MPI_Reduce (&time, &buf, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 
                          MPI_SUM, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == root){
        buf = buf / nprocs;
        cout << buf << "\n";
    }

  MPI_Finalize ( );

}
```

where `time` is each processes sort time.

Comment: Yes, it has MPI_init at the beginning. I think your code either does the sorting by a different single core 5 times, or by 5 cores together in one time? But I want to get the sort time done by 2 cores for 5 times.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand, can you post a minimal code to make this clear? Do they sort in parallel? With MPI, each core runs as a separate instance simultaneously with communication between then made possible using MPI commands. The above code models a run of 5 separate instance of sort (replace time=0.5 with function) which will run simultaneously on 5 cores followed by communication to get an average over all five.

Comment: Why not just run `mpirun -np 2 mpiSort` five times and take the average time of the executable if that's what you want? Note that the whole of the MPI executable will run simultaneously on the number of cores you specify with `mpirun -np`, unlike say openMP where you simply multi-thread over a section.

Comment: I edited the question. I'll try to post a simplified code later on.

Answer (score 0):

Put in a loop is the way to go. I was confused because I got 10 values of `endTime = MPI_Wtime()`, and I only used 5 of them from the root process. Thanks to @EdSmith with his `MPI_Reduce` code, the correct calculated time is the average of the two processes by using `MPI_Reduce`.

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nProcs);

for (int run=0; run<5; run++) {
  ...
  endTime = MPI_Wtime();
  totalTime = endTime - startTime;
  MPI_Reduce (&totalTime, &workTime, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_SUM, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  if (rank == root) {
    paraTime = workTime/nProcs;
  }
  ...
}

MPI_Finalize();
```